# How design android app and server which provide work offline as well online

Tags: android, server, client

I need develop an app which show rates of commodities and that is going to used in very low network bandwidth areas. So  I need to download data whenever network is available/when user allow network use through app switch, but user should be able to see whatever data is downloaded in the app. So I am searching for good client/server design which support my requirement.

I thought one approach where server send data  as per the client request and in the request client will send number of id it wanted fetch with from and start point, but unfortunately currently server guys unable  to do that.

So looking for alternate approaches.

Any article , Any sample will help here.

Answer (score 0):

Save data in local database `(SQLite)` and display  when it is in `online` and display data from `SQLite` when it in `offline`

Comment: I am more interested in client /server protocol which they use for syncing as i mentioned in one of my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Realm](https://realm.io/). Realm provides a very elegant client/server database sync and best of all its free.

Comment: Wanted to develop client and server our own.